# The sqliite db query is not working in postgresql db

Tags: postgresql

i am having a query which is working correctly in SQLite. but its giving error in PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT decks.id, decks.name, count(cards.id) 
from decks 
JOIN cards ON decks.id = cards.did 
GROUP BY cards.did
```

above query is giving error in postgresql.

ERROR:  column "decks.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT decks.id, decks.name, count(cards.id) FROM decks JOIN...

Comment: What are you expecting that query to do/return? What is unclear about the error message?

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: @AD7six  i am having a two table (decks and cards). i want a count of cards in each deck. each deck can have n number of card. deck table will have two colums id and name. cards table will have card_id as id and deck_id as did. in cards table for same deck_id will have n number of cards_id. so i try it with group by deck_id( did) in cards table and used join with decks table (id). it worked perfectly in SQLite but i try it in PostgreSQL its giving error.

Comment: Edit the question please, don’t use comments :). Please do read the above-linked reference too

Answer (score 1):

You can't have columns in the SELECT list, that are not used in an aggregate function or part of the GROUP BY. The fact that SQLite accepts this, is a bug in SQLite. The fact that Postgres rejects this, is correct.

You need to rewrite your query to:

```
SELECT decks.id, decks.name, count(cards.id) 
from decks 
  JOIN cards ON decks.id = cards.did 
GROUP BY decks.id, decks.name;
```

If `decks.id` is the primary key, you can shorten the grouping to `GROUP BY decks.id`